# Is it bad practice to include external JSP file as javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm having a JSP page which has javascript variables which will be generated dynamically on the server side. Now I want to include this JSP page. So I included this page using standard JSP include tag

```
<%@ include file="my_file.jsp" >
```

But I faced an issue in google-chrome browser. The issue is, the scripts in the JSP page is flashed in the browser for half a second. Especially in lower config client machines, this issue reproduced for every 5 refreshes non periodically. So I included this JSP page as javascript file like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_file.jsp"></script>
```

It works fine. But is this bad practice?

This is my my_file.jsp

```
<custom_tag:loadProperties resourceBundle="testBundle" jsVarName="testLocale"/>
```

it has more than 30 custom_tag, each tag will output a js variable like this

```
testLocale="{key1: value1, key2: value2...}";
```

Comment: This will require another extra HTTP request to the server, which may add a little more delay to the page.

Comment: And what do you mean by `the JSP page is flashed in the browser for half a second`

Comment: yeah. The variables in the JSP page is shown in the chrome browser for half of the second, after that the normal page loads.

Comment: So what's your normal page. I think you should give more detail on what your my_file.jsp is and how you use (show) the variables in the displayed page.

Comment: @TwilightSun I have edited my post.

Comment: Are you surrounding `<%@ include file="my_file.jsp" >` with a script tag? I don't see any thing wrong here. It should behave the same either loading js inline or as an outer resource.

Comment: @TwilightSun: Yes it's working fine. But I want to make sure is this bad practice?